# Java error when installing software

Tags: java

When I try to install third party software (SPSS 20) I get this error message:

```
2472: exec: /tmp/install.dir.2799/Linux/resource/jre/jre/bin/java: not found
```

I fixed this issue in wubi by installing sun java and making it env var.

Now I've installed Ubuntu alone and tried the same tricks, but I get that error.

I also get this :  `strings: '/lib/libc.so.6': No such file` .  I did get that with wubi, but it didn't affect the installation.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody needs it still:

I solved this by installing some 32 bit stuff:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

To solve the other error you could possibly try (it was not necessary for me):

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

(the path to libc.so.6 can be found via: `locate libc.so.6`).

Answer (score 0):

In 2016 for Ubuntu 14.04+, the solution is now:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```